# installing jbpm on eclipse with tomcat

Tags: jbpm

I am trying to install jbpm on Eclipse to work with tomcat.

I downloaded jbpm-installer-3.2.7 but do not understand how to install it on eclipse!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go [here](http://docs.jboss.com/jbpm/v4/userguide/html_single/#d0e645) to get detailed instructions on installing version 4. Any reason you are going with the older version?

edit: For version 3.2.7, I got this from the documentation [here](http://docs.jboss.com/jbpm/v3.2/userguide/html_single/):

> You can use your own eclipse (if it is version 3.4+) or you can use the eclipse that the installer downloaded. To install the graphical process designer in eclipse, just use the eclipse update mechanism (Help --> Software Updates --> ...) and point it to the file designer/jbpm-jpdl-designer-site.zip.

Comment: I understood that JBPM 4 is not recommended. Look here: http://community.jboss.org/message/569325 what is your opinion?

Comment: @Odelya - Unfortunately I can't help you with an opinion because I've never used JBPM. However if support isn't their for version 4, then it does make sense to use the previous version. I updated my answer with information for 3.2.7

Comment: Stick with jBPM 3 for now until jBPM 5 comes out, unless you need any specific features of jBPM 4